# Lenovo Y50 continuously disconnects from WIFI - but only when it's plugged in

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-8.1, internet-connection, lenovo-laptop

About a month ago, my computer started disconnecting from the internet (but usually claiming it was still connected to the network with full bars) every 2-3 hours or so. I tried a System Restore, which did work for about 3 days, but then it came back with a vengeance - disconnecting more and more quickly each time. I tried to Restore again, but the problem simply came back a day later.

The only thing I could find to make the internet work again was to restart my modem/router. This was happening on none of the other computers on the network, so I don't think it was a modem/router issue. I don't understand why that worked, but it did. Curiously, a new way I found to fix it was to unplug my laptap. When I do this, it immediately starts working again while unplugged, but I must leave it unplugged for awhile to be able to use it again whilst it is plugged in.

I've tried all of the power management options, both in the network settings and in the power settings (made it so the computer can't shut off the device, put everything on maximum performance). I've tried just about every guide that I could find (most of which recommend the same power maintenance options), and absolutely nothing has worked. My adapter is an Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the Yoga 2 Pro. I went through a painful network adapter driver update which resolved the issue. (Painful because the first driver I downloaded from Lenovo caused the adapter to stop working).

I'd suggest you go to the lenovo website and download all recent versions of network adapters and keep trying the software til one works.